# How to load JavaScript (jQuery) on pjax:ready and document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate, pjax

I am using pjax for most of my pages. For some of them I need to include jQuery scripts.

When I load a page with pjax all scripts in  `$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() { ... }` are working fine, although if the page is loaded directly scripts in above function will not work, and other way round - scripts inside `$(document).ready(function() {...}` wont work if page is loaded with pjax.

Is there a way to detect if the page was loaded with pjax and use document.ready if it wasn't?

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and **removed in jQuery 3.0**.

My quick fix was this:

```
function myFunction() { ... }
$(myFunction)
$(document).on('pjax:end', myFunction)
```